# Problema al hacer consulta sumaria mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Tengo que mostrar para cada pedido la cantidad de ítems que contiene y ordenar el resultado por mayor cantidad de número de ítems.
En la tabla items tengo los campos ord_id que corresponde al nro de pedido, osea, en la tabla pedidos tengo el campo id y los conecto como items.ord_id = pedidos.id
Ahora para hacer lo que planteo propongo el query

```
    SELECT SUM(I.ord_id) AS "Nro Orden", P.id AS "Id Pedido"
FROM item I JOIN pedido P ON (P.id = I.ord_id)
ORDER BY I.cantidad
```

Pero me tira este error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Column 'pedido.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Que podra hacer? Basicamente lo que quiero decirle es que me diga cuantos items tiene un pedido. Ej el pedido 22 tiene 32 items

Comment: No estas agrupando y tienes en uso una función de agregación llamada `SUM` revisa lo que gbianchi aporta en su respuesta para que asimiles que debes corregir

Comment: y donde esta el group by? si no, como sabe que sumar?